# VBA Updating Table Headers from a List

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Table containing a list of Names.

I would like to update a secondary table to have headers that correspond to this list of names (starting from column 2).

Example if my original List contained a,b,c. I would like my secondary table to have column headers of "blank",a,b,c

```
    With Range("Original Table[Names]")
        Range("Secondary Table").HeaderRowRange.Value = .Value
    End With
```

The above gives me errors, however, i can't seem to figure out how to solve this

Comment: Probably need to `Application.Transpose` here.

Comment: I've attempted numerous ways of this, however, still end up with errors

Comment: Also, you can't have a blank table header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Transpose`, and `Resize`.

```
With Range("Original Table[Names]")
    Range("Secondary Table").HeaderRowRange.Cells(2).Resize(,.Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Value)
End With
```

Perhaps a personal preference, but I'd work with `ListObject`s here:

```
Dim origTable As ListObject
Set origTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("insertname").ListObjects("Original Table")

Dim secTable As ListObject
Set secTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("insertname").ListObjects("Secondary Table")

With origTable.ListColumns("Names").DataBodyRange
    secTable.HeaderRowRange.Cells(2).Resize(,.Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Value)
End With
```

Also, note that a column header can't be blank in a table.